# Is it possible to open file in specific encoding in geany?

Tags: locale, geany

My system locale is ru_RU.KOI8-R and I want geany to create all new files in this encoding. In its settings I set "Default encoding (new files)" to "Cyrillic (KOI8-R)" and it works for new files. But when I open any file without cyrillic characters, geany thinks it's in Unicode.

Is there any way to tell geany to open all files in KOI8-R (even if there's no non-ASCII characters inside them) or the only way is to put any character from upper half of codepage to all source files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to work on this problem, but seems that the only way for Geany to force to use an encoding is to have a corresponding line in the beginning of the file.
If file contains UTF-8 characters geany will use this locale.

Among other things i tried the following bellow. You can also give a try your self , in case that works better in your machine.

- To switch localle of my system to Greek `ISO-8859-7` (it was `en_US.UTF-8` before). I had to first install the new local using `dpkg-reconfigure locales`
- To convert a test file from `UTF-8` to desired locale (`ISO-8859-7` in my case) using command `iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-7 c.txt --output=c2.txt`
- To change geany preferences , in Preferences-Files Tab applying `Greek ISO-8859-7` encoding both for new files and also for "Default Encoding (existing non Unicode Files)"

PS: Setting can also be verified/changed directly by look/edit file `~/.config/geany/geany.conf` and look for the lines `pref_editor_default_new_encoding=UTF-8 #changed to ISO-8859-7` and line `pref_editor_default_open_encoding=None #changed to ISO-8859-7`

- Then only thing that really worked is to insert in the beginning of the file the line :
  `# geany_encoding=ISO-8859-7 #`

This solution is described on the [Geany online manual - Infile encoding specification Section.](http://www.geany.org/manual/#in-file-encoding-specification)

As a workaround to avoid opening all your files one by one and appending the above line you could use:

```
echo -e "# geany_encoding=ISO-8859-7 #\n$(cat c.txt)" >c.txt
```

You can also make a loop to quickly "geany-convert" all your files; something like this:

```
for file in "$(find . -type f -name "*.txt");do echo -e "# geany_encoding=ISO-8859-7 #\n$(cat $file)" >$file;done
```

I hope above ideas to help you solve your problem.

You could also check and ask geany devs if forcing encoding during opening a file is in the future plans of Geany.

PS: You could always open the file as it is in Geany, press `reload as <your encoding>` and save. This should save the file in the new encoding.

Comment: Thank you! `//geany_encoding=koi8-r` at beginning of each file solve my problem. Where did you find such an "undocumented feature"?

Comment: @Eddy_Em Welcome :-) Happy that this helped. Online manual of Geany has tons of information available. I already updated my answer to include the Geany Online Manual link (http://www.geany.org/manual/#in-file-encoding-specification) . PS: If you are happy with above solution you might consider to accept this answer.

Comment: @George Vasiliou. Good job done, the problem was long-lived. And now solved! Thank you!.